# Spring jpa "where param is null" not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Reproduced code can be found [here (Github)](https://github.com/anaconda875/bug-spring-jpa--1-is-null).

Sorry for my bad English.

I'm using spring boot web, jpa, mysql to create a simple restful endpoint.

- Spring boot parent version: 2.7.0
- Java version: 11 Oracle

My repo:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR t.name LIKE %?1%)")
    Page<Test> findAll(String keyword, Pageable pageable);
}
```

My api:

```
@GetMapping("/ab")
public Page<Test> ab(CustomPageable pageable) {
    //INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'aa', 1);
    //INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 'a', 2);
    //INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 'b', 3);
    return testRepository.findAll(pageable.getKeyword(), pageable);
}
```

The CustomPageable model:

```
public static class CustomPageable extends PageRequest {

    @Getter
    private final String keyword;

    protected CustomPageable(int page, int size, Sort sort) {
        super(page, size, sort);
        keyword = null;
    }

    public CustomPageable(int page, int size, Sort sort, String keyword) {
        super(page, size, sort);
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }
}
```

My problem is, if the pageable.getKeyword() is null (http://localhost:8181/ab?size=3&sort=name,DESC&page=0), I expect it will return a page contains 3 elements. Actually it return an empty page.

Log:

```
2022-10-02 15:40:00.967  INFO 6560 --- [nio-8181-exec-6] p6spy                                    : #1664700000967 | took 2ms | statement | connection 4| url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_, test0_.status as status3_0_ from test test0_ where ? is null or test0_.name like ? order by test0_.name desc limit ?
select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_, test0_.status as status3_0_ from test test0_ where '%org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue@d41192d%' is null or test0_.name like '%org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue@d41192d%' order by test0_.name desc limit 3;
```

Please take a look at the query `...where '%org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue@d41192d%' is null or test0_.name like '%org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue@d41192d%'...`. I have no idea about '%org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue@d41192d%'.

Please explain to me why my HQL does not work in case keyword is null? Is it my bug or JPA bug? How can I fix this problem?

====================================================================================

NOTE:

If I send the keyword (http://localhost:8181/ab?size=3&sort=name,DESC&page=0&keyword=a), then it return correctly.

Log:

```
2022-10-02 15:42:00.659  INFO 6560 --- [io-8181-exec-10] p6spy                                    : #1664700120658 | took 3ms | statement | connection 6| url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_, test0_.status as status3_0_ from test test0_ where ? is null or test0_.name like ? order by test0_.name desc limit ?
select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_, test0_.status as status3_0_ from test test0_ where '%a%' is null or test0_.name like '%a%' order by test0_.name desc limit 3;
2022-10-02 15:42:00.665  INFO 6560 --- [io-8181-exec-10] p6spy                                    : #1664700120665 | took 4ms | statement | connection 6| url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
select count(test0_.id) as col_0_0_ from test test0_ where ? is null or test0_.name like ?
select count(test0_.id) as col_0_0_ from test test0_ where '%a%' is null or test0_.name like '%a%';
```

Using @Query with HQL is a must, please don't suggest another ways like CriteriaBuilder, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have examined your GitHub project and can say, that, actually, it is a known issue of the `spring-data-jpa` framework of version 2.7.0 and higher. There are registered Issues on GitHub, e.g., [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2548) or [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2570). It had been closed as resolved, but it seems to be not completely fixed, IMHO. So I've started another one [issue there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2653). I have also created a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/2655) with a quick-fix, that makes the framework to behave like before.

So at the moment to overcome this problem you can just downgrade the spring boot version to `2.6.x`, or go with hot fixes, built by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Does this commit fix the problem? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/2654/commits/3c804cf24c4463938da6f629e2de9404338638c3

Comment: There was an incorrect branch matching on GH in my request. I've recreated it and refreshed its link in the answer. And yes, it does fix the problem.

Comment: @SoT Hey! My fix has been finally merged on GH, so look for it in coming up releases

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass value by using `:#{#keyword}` parameter in query. You also need to configure `@Param("keyword")`.

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM TestEntity t WHERE (:#{#keyword} IS NULL OR t.name LIKE %:#{#keyword}%)")
    Page<Test> findAll(@Param("keyword") String keyword, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Param not needed tho

Comment: This issue is a bug in the framework and this is a decent work around for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using positional parameters use named parameters

```
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE (:keyword IS NULL OR t.name LIKE %:keyword%)")
    Page<Test> findAll(@Param("keyword")String keyword, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This doesn't help, result is the same - wrong.